# The more appropriate way to find GameObject in the scene

Tags: unity, c#

Which way is the more appropriate to find GameObject in the scene. 
I know that GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag is faster than GameObject.Find but i wondering whether FindGameObjectWithTag is better solution than this:

```
public GameObject someObject;

public void SelectObject()
{
    someObject.SetActive(true);
    //or whatever i want 
}
```

Comment: By "this" do you mean linking an object in the Inspector to your someObject field?

Comment: Correctly. And after that i select the required object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have objects linked via the inspector and public/serialized fields, you should absolutely do it. It's the best way. `FindObjectWithTag` is for when your objects don't live in the same scene, and they don't have scripts for registering for each other. And finally, it's useful for when you need to reference a script before `Awake` has run, so it may not be found/registered.

The only occasional disadvantage of linked variables is when you need to reference a prefab that you usually won't need (or won't need all the time), and this object has large resources, like a collection of textures. If it's linked/serialized, the prefab will be loaded into RAM.

Note: To clarify, `FindObjectWithTag` will find objects that have not had `Awake` called because of timing, but it will not find inactive objects. (This is how all the `Find*` functions work.)